# MySQL: Efficient Blobbing?

Tags: php, sql, mysql, performance, propel

I'm dealing with blobs of up to - I estimate - about 100 kilo bytes in
size. The data is compressed already.

Storage engine: InnoDB on MySQL 5.1

Frontend: PHP (Symfony with Propel ORM)

Some questions:

- I've read somewhere that it's not good to update blobs, because
  it leads to reallocation, fragmentation, and thus bad
  performance. Is that true? Any reference on this?
- Initially the blobs get constructed by appending data chunks. Each
  chunk is up to 16 kilo bytes in size. Is it more efficient to use a
  separate chunk table instead, for example with fields as below?

  `parent_id, position, chunk`

  Then, to get the entire blob, one would do something like:

  `SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(chunk ORDER BY position) FROM chunks WHERE parent_id = 187`

  The result would be used in a PHP script.
- Is there any difference between the types of blobs, aside from
  the size needed for meta data, which should be negligible.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT() isn't a good candidate for this. By default it's limited to a max length of 1024 bytes (though you can change this with the group_concat_max_len). You'd also have to be very careful constructing the query - what happens if the chunks are grouped/concatted in the wrong order?

Comment: I don't see a problem with the limit, as it can be extended. Concerning getting concatenation in the right order: That's why I propose the `position` field. Shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: just select each chunk and concat them in PHP. or, if you're outputting them, output them without concatting them at all.

Comment: araqnid: Why should I do that? What's the advantage? In fact, I am assuming that MySQL is way more efficient for that step. By the way, the concatenated result is then post-processed. It is not sent to the screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you're creating and deleting data in a table, you will get fragmentation of table's data structure.

I don't think you can gain anything by splitting blobs into chunks — you don't gain anything by fragmenting data before DB fragments it :)

You can defragment table's structure by rebuilding it (`OPTIMIZE TABLE` in MySQL).

I could not find information how MySQL stores blobs on disk. If it stores them alongside other row data, then you could use clustered index (PK in InnoDB, `ALTER TABLE ORDER BY` in MyISAM) to require particular order of data in table's datafile (e.g. ordered by popularity to create "hot" area which might improve caching and reduce seeking a bit).

In addition to fragmentation of database's own structure, there's problem of fragmentation of table's file in filesystem.

Even if you only inserted data to the table with zero fragmentation of the table itself, the filesystem that holds the table file will sooner or later fragment it on disk. It's unavoidable on safe filesystems as they never update file's data in-place.

*if* fragmentation is a problem, then I'd attack it at lowest level possible. Don't store blobs in the database, store only some references to files on disk.

Filesystems are closer to the physical disk, so they can deal with fragmentation much better than DB query that's few levels of abstraction above it. Some filesystems automatically defragment *small* files, but leave large files fragmented.

Or you might just throw hardware at the problem — use RAID, add a ton of RAM for disk/DB caches or use SSD.

And of course you've benchmarked it carefully and know that fragmentation is a problem in a first place, right?

Comment: In fact, I've discovered that - as of now - the fragmentation is not an issue. After introducing compression, the blobs are - in general - quite small (up to a couple of kilo bytes) and append operations are infrequent. So priorities have changed a bit. However, I am still interested in the difference between the blob data types. Also, I recall reading that MySQL stores big blobs in a different place than small blobs, and that this is much less efficient. That would be another reason to use a separate chunks table, asides from - yes - fragmentation. Not an issue though, at the moment.